# Why do I get a syntax error in my bash script?

Tags: linux, bash

Here is the script I have been trying:

```
#!/bin/bash
    case “$1” in 

    [0-9][A-Z])
    echo “ <<Usage: $0 >> Script5.rc argb  ”
    ;;

./Script.rc
```

But when I run it, I get the following error:

> syntax error near unexpected token

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What's the deal with those crazy quotes?

Comment: @sarnold : yes, crazy quotes, good catch! That could do it.

Answer (score 6):

Two problems:

1) Those are unicode quotes. Those can eff up a script. Do not write code in microsoft word.

2) You forgot to end your case.

```
case "$1" in  

[0-9][A-Z])
  echo " <<Usage: $0 >> Script5.rc argb  "
  ;;  
esac
```

Comment: +1, I liked the "do not write code in microsoft word" commandment ;-)

Comment: Wordpress tends to mess up quotes too. Do not copy code from random blogs. ;)

Answer (score 1):

`case` is supposed to end with `esac`. So, at the very least your code sample is incomplete.